# GNUStep's ProjectCenter IDE not working properly on 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, software-center, 64-bit, ide, objective-c

I installed Objective C Programming Environment on 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
earlier. Now I got to know that an IDE of GNUStep called ProjectCenter also got installed along with that environment.
But ProjectCenter is not working properly. All the features of the Objective C Programming Environment are working properly except ProjectCenter.

When I open ProjectCenter, an application named Log opens up. I also get a dialog box in Log containing options like PC, Info, Project, File, Hide, Quit. Only two options "Hide" and "Quit" are working.

I don't want to reinstall the whole environment. Reinstalling ProjectCenter from Ubuntu Software doesn't seem to resolve the issue. So suggest me a method to resolve this issue!

Comment: Ubuntu includes GCC's Objective C compiler so you can compile your programs via `gcc` and debug using `gdb` you could use `gedit` which support objective C syntax highlighting for files editing.

Comment: I was till now using Geany. But when I found ProjectCenter, I thought I should give it a try as it is an IDE. Also I was getting errors while compiling Objective C programs in Geany. That's why, I wish to use it.

Comment: It seems to me that ProjectCenter has a lot of bugs! That's why, it is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the correct behaviour of ProjectCenter and other GNUstep apps, though that probably comes as a surprise when you're used to other environments like Unity. Many applications based on other systems will open a blank document or a wizard when you launch them, but often GNUstep applications do not. They're designed to just start, then wait for you to tell them what to do.

The thing you call a dialog with File, Project etc. is a menu, like the menu bar that goes across the top of the screen or the window in other applications. You should find that clicking on Project brings up a sub-menu, which includes "New...", and clicking on *that* lets you create a new project where you can write your Objective-C.

The GNUstep documentation [is here](http://www.gnustep.org/developers/documentation.html), unfortunately the link to the user experience guide isn't working.